# Python regex statement

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to create a regex statement in Python 2.7.8 that will substitute characters.  It will work like this...

```
ó -> o
ú -> u
é -> e
á -> a
í -> i
ù,ú  -> u
```

These are the only unicode characters that I would like to change.  Such unicode characters as, `ë, ä` I don't want to change.  So the word, `thójlà` will become `tholja`.  I'm sure there is a way so that I don't have to create all the regex separately like below.

```
word = re.sub(ur'ó', ur'o', word)
word = re.sub(ur'ú', ur'u', word)
word = re.sub(ur'é', ur'e', word)
....
```

I've been trying to figure this out but haven't had any luck.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you want regex? This sounds like a job for `replace()`

Comment: You are not changing the `à`, the result should be tholjà

Answer (score 4):

Try with `str.translate and maketrans`...

```
print('thójlà'.translate(str.maketrans('óúéáíùú', 'oueaiuu')))
# thojlà
```

This way you ensure the only substitutions you want to make.

If you had many strings to change, you should assign your maketrans to a variable, like

```
table = str.maketrans('óúéáíùú', 'oueaiuu')
```

and then, each string can be translated as

```
s.translate(table)
```

Comment: Nice. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." and this is it.

Comment: Note, the code above is for Python 3. In Python 2 it's `string`, not `str`: `print 'thójlà'.translate(string.maketrans('óúéáíùú', 'oueaiuu'))`

Answer (score 3):

With String's `replace()` function you can do something like:

```
x = "thójlà"                  
>>> x
'thójlà'
>>> x = x.replace('ó','o')
'thojlà'
>>> x = x.replace('à','a')
'thojla'
```

A generalized way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

replace_dict = {
    'á':'a',
    'à':'a',
    'é':'e',
    'í':'i',
    'ó':'o',
    'ù':'u',
    'ú':'u'
}

str1 = "thójlà"

for key in replace_dict:
    str1 = str1.replace(key, replace_dict[key])

print(str1) #prints 'thojla'
```

A third way, if your list of character mappings is getting too large:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

replace_dict = {
    'a':['á','à'],
    'e':['é'],
    'i':['í'],
    'o':['ó'],
    'u':['ù','ú']
}

str1 = "thójlà"

for key, values in replace_dict.items():
    for character in values:
        str1 = str1.replace(character, key)

print(str1)
```

Comment: is there a way that I can do this without having to create a statement for each character?  I could have done that with re.sub but that's what I want to avoid in case the list of characters to be changed becomes large.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I also added a third method.

Comment: @RPGillespie, to make it a bit more efficient, you can do: `for key, values in replace_dict:`, `for character in values:`

Comment: the dictionary replace technique could be pretty slow if there are a lot of replacement characters and/or the replacement text is long.

Comment: @twasbrillig I never realized you could do that!

Comment: Oops, it was actually `for key, values in replace_dict.items():` but it looks like you figured that out already.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use external packages, the easiest way, i think, would be using [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1). For example:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

print(unidecode('thójlà'))
# prints: thojla
```

Comment: what if I have other unicode characters that I don't want to substitute will those characters be affected?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, all non-ascii characters will be transliterated.

Comment: Maybe there are some options to specify which characters are changed and which not. Dont know about this. I assumed yo want to change everting.